# Only show items with a particular criteria in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to show only items that meet a certain criteria in an array. At the moment I am outputting everything in the array.
What I've got so far:

```
$records = $d->get("FoundCount");
$result = array();
for($i = 1; $ <= $record; $i++){

// various array components
$show_published = $d->field(show_published); //this is the variable from the DB that will determine if the item is shown on the page. Yes/no string.

if($show_published == 'Yes'){
 $results[] = new Result(//various array components, $show_published, //more things);
}
```

This seems to output all items, including the ones labeled as `'No'` .

Any guidance would be great. I have only been using php for a few months now.

Comment: How can we tell whats wrong when you using arbitrary constants, variables, methods, objects and syntax errors in your example?

Comment: In for loop instead of $d->field, try $record->field

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness of my code, it contains information that I am not able to share so have to use generic terms instead. Alot of the variables contain the business name and private information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're familiar with `composer` and how to install / use php packages.
If you are, you can add `illuminate/support` package as a dependency for your project and use its `Collection` to filter records - something along the lines of:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

$collection = new Collection($records);

$outputArray = $collection->filter(function($object) {

    return (string) $object->field('show_published') === 'Yes';

})->toArray();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections

After this, the `$outputArray` will contain only records that have `show_published` flag set to `Yes`.

Alternatively you could use php's native function `array_filter` in pretty much the same manner:

```
$outputArray = array_filter($records, function($object) {

    return (string) $object->field('show_published') === 'Yes';

});
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Use `array_filter` instead of the `if` loop?

Comment: Yes - you put your condition inside of the closure (function) that is the second argument to the `array_filter` - it simply filters records and as long as function returns true - these records will be included in the `$outputArray`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example on how to create a new filtered array based on the criteria of strings starting with the character 'b'.  I'm not sure what your criteria is but you could certainly take this approach and modify it to suit your needs.

```
 //Original array of things that are un-filtered
        $oldArray = array("Baseball", "Basketball", "Bear", "Salmon", "Swordfish");

 //An empty filtered array that we will populate in the loop below, based on our criteria.
        $filteredArray = array();

        foreach($oldArray as $arrayValue) {
                 //Our criteria is to only add strings to our 
                //filtered array that start with the letter 'B'
            if($arrayValue[0] == "B")
            {
                array_push($filteredArray, $arrayValue);
            }
        }
 //Our filtered array will only display 
 //our 3 string items that start with the character 'B'
        print_r($filteredArray);
```

Hope it helps!  If not, feel free to reach out.